# enabling paging leads to triple fault

Tags: c, nasm, paging, gdt

In case this helps somebody in the future:

- check if the global descriptor table is working
- check if the elements of page table entry struct are ordered correctly

This code worked for me:

gdt.s

```
section .data
gdt:
    .null:
        dq 0
    .code:
        dw 0xFFFF
        dw 0x0000
        db 0x00
        db 0x9A
        db 0xCF
        db 0x00
    .data:
        dw 0xFFFF
        dw 0x0000
        db 0x00
        db 0x92
        db 0xCF
        db 0x00

gdtr:
    dw $-gdt-1
    dd gdt

section .text

global init_global_descriptor_table
init_global_descriptor_table:
    lgdt [gdtr]
    jmp 0x08:.reload_cs

.reload_cs:
    mov ax, 0x10
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax
    ret
```

paging.c

```
enum flags {
    Present = 1 << 0,
    ReadWrite = 1 << 1,
    AccessAll = 1 << 2,
    WriteThroughCashing = 1 << 3,
    DisableCashing = 1 << 4,
    Accessed = 1 << 5,
    Dirty = 1 << 6,     // only for page-table-entries
    MPages = 1 << 7,
    Global = 1 << 8,    // only for page-table-entries
};

struct entry {
    unsigned int flags : 9;
    unsigned int available : 3;
    unsigned int addr : 20;
};

extern void load_paging_directory(int *ptr);

void init_paging() {
    struct entry *dir = (struct entry *)0x00105000;
    struct entry *t1 = (struct entry *)0x00106000;      

    for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
        dir[i] = (struct entry){0};
        if (i <= 262) t1[i] = (struct entry){Present | ReadWrite, 0, i};
    }

    dir[0] = (struct entry){Present, 0, (int)t1 >> 12};
    load_paging_directory((int *)dir);
}
```

paging_asm.s

```
global load_paging_directory
load_paging_directory:
    push ebp,
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp + 8]
    mov cr3, eax
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x80000001
    mov cr0, eax   
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Comment: What is your environment? It also doesn't look like a beginner-level project.

Comment: I use qemu for emulation and
gcc cross compiler with target i686-elf with flags -std=gnu99 -ffreestanding -g

Comment: I assume the reboot is a triple fault, since you don't have any exception handlers.  Your emulator should be able to show you what the fault actually is.  You might try bochs instead of qemu; it generally has better development features (including a built-in debugger).

Comment: the for loop sets dir to 0 for some reason

Comment: What is `0x00105000` address? Why not `malloc`.

Comment: I don't see how that could happen, unless you have mistakenly set up the stack to overlap your page tables, or in some other way have not set things up correctly for compiled C code.  I think you're going to need to create a [mcve] with all the code necessary to build, boot and run everything up to this point.  Explain your build process precisely as well, since there are a lot of ways that mistakes there can subtly screw up runtime.

Comment: @i486: This is boot code, no standard library functions are available.  Using absolute addresses are about all we can do.

Comment: I was trying to get a basic understanding of how operating systems work by essentially copying all of the code from osdev wiki. I would have tried to implement malloc after paging.

Comment: Try to assign each member `t1[i].addr = i; t1[i].available = 0; ...` and `memset( dir + i, 0, sizeof dir[i] );`.

Comment: Just adding the linker script doesn't make this a [mcve].  The goal is for a more experienced person to be able to test out your code with their own tools.  They're more likely to solve the problem this way than by just reading the code. Think about it this way: given only what's in your question, can a stranger build and run your program, and observe the offending behavior?  If not, then you don't have a MRE yet.

Comment: @i486 Thank you; this solves the problem with dir being 0. Still would be nice to know why it became this way in the first place. Setting cr0 still crashes everything though.

Comment: Hi @WernerDrasche, glad you got it solved.  The usual way on this site to handle a problem that you resolve by yourself is to leave the question the same, and use the "Answer Your Question" button to add your own answer explaining the solution, then click the check mark to accept your own answer.  That makes it clear in question listings, statistics, etc, that the question is answered; without an accepted answer, it makes it look like the question still needs attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question has been solved using this struct:

```
struct entry {
    unsigned int flags : 9;
    unsigned int available : 3;
    unsigned int addr : 20;
};
```